# Как сделать так, что бы при наведении на блок, кнопка, находящаяся внутри блока, тоже меняла цвет?

Tags: html, css

необходимо сделать так, что бы при наведении на блок, кнопка, находящаяся внутри блока, тоже меняла цвет.

На данный момент имеется такая картина:[Без наведения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFzsE.png)

[image: После наведения]

Необходимо, чтобы кнопка тоже меняла свой цвет, а картинка менялась на другую, Белую (она у меня есть), как этого достичь?

Фрагмент кода CSS:

```
.service_card:hover {
  background: #00897b;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px  #a9bcb9;
  cursor: pointer;
  color:white;
  transition: 0.3s; 
}
```

Фрагмент кода HTML:

```
<div class="service_card">
  <img src="IMG/smartphone.png" alt="">
  <h3>Reserch</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure at enim sapiente vero tenetur rer</p>
  <input type="submit" class="submit_service" value="READ MORE">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.service_card:hover > input {
  background-color: #00897b;
}
```